# Dynamic 2d array, syntax error JavaScript and Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I heard tat you cannot use razor within a JavaScript but I am not sure if this is true since it accepted the first line of my code but complains about the rest. I have a list in my model and I am trying got get a collection of one element in a JavaScript

```
  function CollectExt() {
            var numberOfLines = '@Model.NumberOfLines';
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
                var extCollection = {(i+1): '@Model.PhoneDisplay[i].dnorpattern' };
            }

        }
```

I want do declare an array and fill it up depending on the number of lines I have.

**EDIT**
I just tried this, but it does not see the 'i' inside the for loop

```
 function CollectExt() {
            var numberOfLines = '@Model.NumberOfLines';
            var collection = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
                numberOfLines.push('@Model.PhoneDisplay[i].dnorpattern');
            }
        }
```

Comment: _"... but it does not see the 'i' inside the for loop"_. That's because the `i` is inside the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript can't run C# code. Your loop needs to be in Razor. But you don't even need a loop in this case.

```
function CollectExt() {
    var stuff = '@string.Join(",", Model.PhoneDisplay.Select(p => p.dnorpattern))';
    var collection = stuff.split(",");
}
```

Comment: nice trick, this collection could be accessed like an array right?

Comment: Yes. `stuff.split` is a JS function, which splits a string by a given delimiter and returns an array.